# Search & replace a constant string with a variable one inside that file

Tags: replace

I asked this question on a different forum, but got no answers. Someone advised me to post this question here on stackoverflow.

I have hundreds of HTML documents named as 001.html 002.html 003.html and so on. All of these HTML files contain multiple constant "F0" string. Also, these HTML files contain a single *variable* string {PABC}, where "ABC" refers to the title number. For example:

```
001.html has F0 string(s) and a string {P001}.
002.html has F0 string(s) and a string {P002}.
003.html has F0 string(s) and a string {P003}.
```

and so on. How do I replace all "F0" occurrences within these HTML files with their corresponding "{PABC}" strings? Let's say, I have 001.html that has multiple F0's and a "{P001}" in it. I want to replace all "F0" occurrences with a "{P001}". Same thing for 002.html, replacing F0's with a "{P002}". How can I perform a batch operation for all HTML files?

Is there any good Text Editor [with regular expressions for REPLACEing a variable found in the file] that can do it, and if so, how? So far I have tried UltraEdit, Funduc Studio Pro and others with no fruitful results.

Thank you.

Comment: In other words, the problem is to replace a line in a file with a different but variable line found inside the same file; and to batch operate this to hundreds of HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

That's fairly easy with Vim.

```
$ vim *.html
:argdo %s/\<F0\>/\='P'.fnamemodify(expand('%'), ':t:r')/ge | update
:q
```

- `expand('%')` returns the name of the current file.
- `fnamemodify(x, ':t:r')` returns the tail (`:t`) of `x` with the extension removed (`:r`)
- `\=` evaluates the following expression and uses that as the replacement
- `:%s/\<F0\>/.../ge` substitutes all `F0` strings that aren't internal to a larger word with the replacement in the entire buffer and doesn't error if there are no matches for the search.
- `|` is how Vim specifies multiple commands on a single command line
- `update` saves the file, only if it is modified
- `:argdo` runs the following commands for all items in the argument list
- `:q` exits Vim

You could also change it around a little so it operates on one file and then run that once for each file.

```
vim -e -s -c '%s/\<F0\>/\="P".fnamemodify(expand("%"), ":t:r")/ge' -c x 001.html
```

The main difference here is that Vim is being run in script mode (`-e -s`) and the `update` and `q` commands are replaced by the `x` command.

Comment: Since I have never used Vim, how do I run that command on a VIM for windows. Then, also I couldn't figure how to navigate to directory where all HTML file are located. Any tips?

Comment: Vim typically adds itself to the right-click menu in Explorer.  You should just be able to select all the files, right-click, `Edit with single Vim` and then run the `:argdo` and `:q` commands.